# can you help me changing the extension of a file?

Tags: php, exec, exe, executable

Can you please help me to change the extension of an exectable file (.exe) to another file ( .jpg ; .pdf ) but the executable file has tu run in normal parametres.

Thank you

Comment: So you want to learn the techniques used for spreading malware?

Comment: hello . do you have skype?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend that, having a file in windows named jpg, and having it execute would allow you to execute code that the user may not have wanted to allow. 
If you need to run an Executable, use the exe format. 
If you are doing this to hack, don't.